# How to disable inspect element?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

Is it possible to disable the inspect element from the user-end this is about the additional website's security. TIA

Disable the f12 and right click of my website

Comment: No. That's not a security strategy anyway.

Comment: Yes there is way to disable inspect element. here is a code. https://codepen.io/smitdudhat/pen/jOeNzpG . but make sure there is more way to open inspect element. we can't hide that option. you need to develop your website more secure from your end.